# Template format error: Every Mappings attribute must be a String or a List

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to have some quick references at the top of my CloudFormation template, so that I don't have to write out a complex reference every time i need it throughout the template.

So I wrote this:

```
Mappings:
  StandardResourcesMap:
    AWSExecuteApi:
      string: !Join [ ':' , ['arn', !Sub '${AWS::Partition}', 'execute-api', !Sub '${AWS::Region}', !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}'] ]
    AWSLambdaFunctions:
      string: !Join [ ':' , ['arn', !Sub '${AWS::Partition}', 'apigateway', !Sub '${AWS::Region}', 'lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'] ]
```

*The rest of the CloudFormation template follows this, and, without the lines above, the template deploys (an S3 bucket, DynamoDB table and a python 3.7-based Lambda).*

The hope was that I could then just use:

```
!FindInMap [StandardResourcesMap,AWSExecuteApi,string]
```

whenever i needed the long-winded value, however the template fails validation with:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template format error: Every Mappings attribute must be a String or a List.
```

as the title says.

I have tried a number of variations on the `Mappings` such as using the `!Ref` variant:

```
Mappings:
  StandardResourcesMap:
    AWSExecuteApi:
      string: !Join [ ':' , ['arn', !Ref 'AWS::Partition', 'execute-api', !Ref 'AWS::Region', !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'] ]
    AWSLambdaFunctions:
      string: !Join [ ':' , ['arn', !Ref 'AWS::Partition', 'apigateway', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'] ]
```

and I just get pulled up on various validation errors, centring on the one presented above.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check https://garbe.io/blog/2017/07/17/cloudformation-hacks/, Sub example is very nice.

Comment: wow. that does look useful - its a pity that there's not one example of a join in there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is this: `You cannot include parameters, pseudo parameters, or intrinsic functions in the Mappings section.` [Mappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html)

Comment: aha! - that's it! thanks so much. Two things: (1) Terrible error message - it certainly didn't suggest what the problem was. (2) I was really hoping that I could store chains of references, so that I didn't have to repeat a block like this everywhere. Know of any way to do that?

Comment: I am also looking for similar solution